# Cannot redirect error to custom page using Razor pages (net core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am a beginner on `Razor` pages and trying to `Re-direct` all bad requests to a custom error page but it keeps giving me 500 error. I am using this document as reference.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors

this is what I tried:

1. On my `Startup.cs` I have the following:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");
}
```

2. My `Error.cshtml` page looks like this:

```
@page "{id}"
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}
```

3. My `Error.cshtml.cs` look like this:

```cs
public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
{
    return Page();
}

public IActionResult OnPost(int id)
{
    return Page();
}

public void OnGet()
{
    RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
}
```

but no matter what invalid `URL` I type in the browser it seems to re-direct to the custom page but looks like I get `500` error. Can someone point me on what I am doing wrong.

thank you!

[image]

Comment: 500 means internal server error, so you need to debug the application

Comment: The url has 404 in it. 404 is not a page name it is a status code. Make a page named Error and then try to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` with `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` and pass `?code={0}` as query format.

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?code={0}");
    //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
{
    //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?code={0}");
}
```

and show status code in view like this

**Error.cshtml.cs**

Add `int? code` in `OnGet` method

```cs
public int Code { get; set; }
//public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
//{
//    return Page();
//}
public void OnGet(int? code)
{
    Code = code ?? 0;
    RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
}
```

**Error.cshtml**

Add `@page "{code?}"` and `<p>Error Code : @Model.Code </p>`

```
@page "{code?}"
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<p>Error Code : @Model.Code </p>
@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to the <strong>Development</strong> environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the "/{0}" from

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");
```

That would redirect to **/Error** instead of **/Error/500** which may not exist.
Farhad's answer may be better if you need the code.